# Can't unbind the off click event on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button named check amount and some select fields. If I choose something in a select field another select field appears (select.select_operator). I want to make a script which disables the click action on the check amount button until select.select_operator field appears. I tried to add setInterval function but I have some alertifies and it is shown too many times. I also tried to unbind the off click event in the first if statement, but it doesn't work. The code looks like this:

```
$("a#checkAmount").one("mouseover",function(){
        if($("select.select_operator").length){

        }
        else {
            $("a#checkAmount").off("click");

            alertify.error("Please select a condition first");
            $("select.select_condition").effect( "highlight", 
          {color:"#ffff87"}, 2250 );
        }

    });
```

What can I do to unbind off(click) from the check amount button when select.select_operator appears?

Comment: Uhm `$("select.select_operator").length`returns a number not a different datatype.

Comment: _can't unbind the off click_. ;-)

Comment: Did you add the `click` handler with `.one()`? The JQuery docs say `.off()` only removes handlers that have been attached with `on()`, so perhaps there's the problem?

Comment: No, I can't do this. I have to remove the click action from the button and then I need to turn it on when specific condition (select.select_operator) appears on the page (so the check amount button is clickable on this condition)

Comment: `one` is work once.. then what you unbind?

Comment: Girish, it should work once, but when the select field appears, the button is still unclickable and it should be then clickable

Comment: Could you post the code you use the bind the click event?

Comment: The whole code of the script is above, icke

Comment: You don't bind a click event anywhere then, you bind mouseover and then unbind click within the handler.

Comment: Icke, I don't want to bind a click. I just want to disable the click event (button is unclickable) when mouse is over the button and then when specific element appears on the page (select.select_operator) I want to make the button clickable again.

Comment: You're trying to unbind a click event. So at some point you must have bound it. If not via JS then at least somewhere in the HTML?

Comment: I don't. The button is clickable so I want to make it unclickable when mouse pointer is over this button and off.('click') works fine for this task. But later on some condition I want to make it clickable again and I don't know how to do this, because the button is unclickable.

Comment: You lost me there. Perhaps edit your question to make this point a bit clearer. You made the button unclickable? Now you want to make it clickable again? Then you need to attach a click event to it again after you removed it. (Am I missing the point of the whole question?)

Comment: Yes. this is exactly what I want to do, but I do not know where to put it to make the script work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your problem right this time. :)

Enabling the button should go in the same place where you set the condition for it to be clickable again.

I made a small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmktfLfw/) to demonstrate what I mean.

If you're having trouble with the click event of the button firing too often, make sure you detach other handlers first:

```
$('#clickme').off('click');
$('#clickme').on('click',function(){alert('You selected something, good boy');});
```